# R: How to align lines with polygon

Tags: r, plot, graph

I'm unable to get the polygon to align with the curve. I'll put the code here:

```
critvalmax <- qt(0.975,df=4)
critvalmin <- qt(0.025,df=4)
xvals <- seq(-5, 5, length=100) 
fx.samp.t <- dt(xvals, df=4)

plot(xvals, dnorm(xvals), col="white") 
lines(xvals, fx.samp.t, lty=1, lwd=2)
abline(v= critvalmin, lty=2)
abline(v= critvalmax, lty=2)
abline(h=0, lty=3)
polygon(cbind(c(critvalmin, xvals[xvals>=critvalmin & xvals<=critvalmax], critvalmax, critvalmax), c(0, dt(critvalmin, df=4), fx.samp.t[xvals>=critvalmin & xvals<=critvalmax], 0)), density=10, lty=3)
```

[image: The problematic plot]
The result is that the polygon is drawn a bit to the right and I can't find a solution by myself. Also, the left bottom corner doesn't seem to fill properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed some variables in your `polygon` like the second `critvalmax` and `dt(critvalmin, df=4)` and `cbind`. The `dt(critvalmin, df=4)` seems to have slightly moved your polygon by `0.02558082` to right. You can use the following code:

```r
critvalmax <- qt(0.975,df=4)
critvalmin <- qt(0.025,df=4)
xvals <- seq(-5, 5, length=100) 
fx.samp.t <- dt(xvals, df=4)

plot(xvals, dnorm(xvals), col="white") 
lines(xvals, fx.samp.t, lty=1, lwd=2)
abline(v= critvalmin, lty=2)
abline(v= critvalmax, lty=2)
abline(h=0, lty=3)
polygon(c(critvalmin, xvals[xvals>=critvalmin & xvals<=critvalmax], critvalmax), c(0, fx.samp.t[xvals>=critvalmin & xvals<=critvalmax], 0), density=10, lty=3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

`polygon` only needs your x and y:

> vectors containing the coordinates of the vertices of the polygon.

And the `density`:

> the density of shading lines, in lines per inch. The default value of
> NULL means that no shading lines are drawn. A zero value of density
> means no shading nor filling whereas negative values and NA suppress
> shading (and so allow color filling).